# rechart error data.slice is not a funcation React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

this is my api call

```
    const getPeso = async () => {
    const jwt = sessionStorage.getItem('Token')
    const user = jwtDecode(jwt)



    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('Token')
    console.log(token)
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/animals/animal/client?clientId=" + user.id, {
        method: "get",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `${token}`,
        },
    })
    const dados = await response.json();
    setData(dados)


};
```

and this is my rechart

```
<LineChart
            width={650}
            height={300}
            data={setData()}
            margin={{
                top: 20,
                right: 50,
                left: 50,
                bottom: 70
            }}
        >
            <CartesianGrid vertical={false} />
            <XAxis dataKey="data" axisLine={false} tickLine={false} tickMargin={10} color={'#494949'} fontWeight={'500'} />
            <YAxis dataKey='peso' domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']} tickCount={4} axisLine={false} tickLine={false} tickMargin={10} color={'#494949'} fontWeight={'500'} />
            <Tooltip />

            <Line
                type="monotone"
                dataKey="peso"
                stroke="#000000"
                activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
            />
        </LineChart>
```

im getting data.slice is not a funcation error anyone can help? i think my chart data dont support functions so im wondering how i can pass my api into an variable array and use it on chart

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing function in chart instead of data

Try something like this:-

```
<LineChart
  width={650}
  height={300}
  data={data}
  margin={{
    top: 20,
    right: 50,
    left: 50,
    bottom: 70
   }}
>
  <CartesianGrid vertical={false} />
  <XAxis dataKey="data" axisLine={false} tickLine={false} tickMargin={10} color={'#494949'} fontWeight={'500'} />
  <YAxis dataKey='peso' domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']} tickCount={4} axisLine={false} tickLine={false} tickMargin={10} color={'#494949'} fontWeight={'500'} />
  <Tooltip />

  <Line
    type="monotone"
    dataKey="peso"
    stroke="#000000"
    activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
  />
</LineChart>
```

Comment: i did that but my chart is wihtout any data because i declared this const [data, setData] = useState([])

Comment: after api call is it not populating?

Comment: no but my api gets data i used console.log

Comment: can you share output of console.log?